# Array in IN() clause oracle PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am passing String array(plcListchar) to Stored Procedure, i would like to use this String array in IN() clause.

i can not use plcListchar directly in IN() clause.
Let me show how i am crating plcListchar  string array in JAVA.

```
 String array[] = {"o", "l"}; 
 ArrayDescriptor des = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("CHAR_ARRAY", con);
 ARRAY array_to_pass = new ARRAY(des,con,array);            
 callStmtProductSearch.setArray(4, array_to_pass);
```

for crating CHAR_ARRAY,

```
create or replace type CHAR_ARRAY as table of varchar2;
```

i want use plcListchar in IN clause. the following is my Stored Procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE product_search(
            status IN varchar2, 
            plcList IN varchar2,
            i_culture_id IN number,
            plcListchar IN CHAR_ARRAY,
            status_name OUT  varchar2, 
            culture_code  OUT varchar2)
AS  
    CURSOR search_cursor IS
    SELECT p.status_name, p.culture_code
                FROM PRISM_ITEM_cultures@prism p
                WHERE p.publishable_flag=1 
                AND p.isroll =0 
                AND status = '-1'
                AND p.plc_status IN (   );
 BEGIN
           OPEN search_cursor;
           FETCH search_cursor INTO status_name, culture_code ;
           CLOSE search_cursor;
 END;
```

Could you please suggest me how to use, if you like to suggest any other logic, it is great.

Comment: I tried this:

`AND p.plc_status IN (SELECT x.*
                       FROM TABLE(plcListchar) AS x);`

and Oracle raises

`PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements`

I'm also looking for a solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming that your collection is defined in SQL, not just in PL/SQL, you can use the `TABLE` operator (the definition you posted isn't syntactically valid-- you'd need to specify a length for the `VARCHAR2`)

```
AND p.plc_status IN (SELECT column_value
                       FROM TABLE( plcListchar ))
```

Since I don't have your tables, an example using the `SCOTT` schema

```
SQL> create type ename_tbl is table of varchar2(30);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  declare
  2    l_enames ename_tbl := ename_tbl( 'KING', 'SMITH' );
  3  begin
  4    for i in (select *
  5                from emp
  6               where ename in (select column_value
  7                                 from table( l_enames )))
  8    loop
  9      dbms_output.put_line( 'ENAME = ' || i.ename );
 10    end loop;
 11* end;
SQL> /
ENAME = KING
ENAME = SMITH

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Note: The code create type ename_tbl is table of varchar2(30); creates a new user-defined type (UDT) in Oracle called ename_tbl. This UDT is a table of varchar2(30) columns, which means that it can store a collection of strings, each of which can be up to 30 bytes long.

Comment: Hi! I tried something similar but got an error. I have posted a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516515/using-nested-table-variables-in-sql-queries-inside-anonymous-blocks-or-stored-pr . Any help would be greatly appreciated.