# WHERE IN with column content

Tags: sql, plsql

I got the following statement:

```
SELECT XYZ FROM ABC WHERE ID IN (123)
```

At the moment I made the 123 as a configuration parameter in a separate table:

```
SELECT XYZ FROM ABC WHERE ID IN (SELECT CONTENT FROM c_configuration WHERE IDENTIFIER = "ID")
```

Now the content from the c_configuration parameter changed to "123, 456".
Is there any better way then splitting the field content at "," and insert them into an array and put the array in the `WHERE ID IN ( ARRAY )` part?

Thank you in advance
Matt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515772/array-in-in-clause-oracle-plsql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try out the following code:

```
SELECT XYZ 
FROM ABC 
WHERE ID IN 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(CONTENT,'[^,]+', 1, level))
  FROM c_configuration
  WHERE IDENTIFIER = 'ID'
  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(CONTENT, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d2330/1)

Comment: Wow, thats pretty nice and smoooth. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to split up the csv value or use dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a function like this:

```
create function dbo.fn_SplitString 
(
    @str nvarchar(max), 
    @separator char(1)
)
returns table
AS
return (
with tokens(p, a, b) AS (
    select 
        cast(1 as bigint), 
        cast(1 as bigint), 
        charindex(@separator, @str)
    union all
    select
        p + 1, 
        b + 1, 
        charindex(@separator, @str, b + 1)
    from tokens
    where b > 0
)
select
    substring(
        @str, 
        a, 
        case when b > 0 then b-a ELSE LEN(@str) end) 
    AS id
from tokens
);
```

This function returns a "array/set" where you can use in your 'where in' statement

```
select * 
from myTable 
where ID in (
    select id 
    from fn_fn_SplitString(select CONTENT from c_configuration where IDENTIFIER = "ID",','))
```